# GitHub Pages: untracked files

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Added website files to my cloned repo on my desktop. I'm trying to push these changes to Github, but keep getting this error message:

```
Untracked files:
    LICENSE
    css/
    events.html
    font-awesome/
    fonts/
    img/
    index.html
    join.html
    js/
    less/
    page.html

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Comment: `git add` is called for, no?

Answer (score 4):

It's not an error, this is just the usual state when you have made some changes to your project. Add your files to the staging area, create a commit, and then push your changes to the remote repository:

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
3. `git push origin master`

You should read more about what git is and how to use it, you may find [this tutorial](https://try.github.io) useful.